# How to add a current VM to another cloud service without having to rebuild the vm in Azure?

Tags: azure

We have a few servers in Azure that are running the same service. We would like them to be part of the same availability set. How do you add these servers together in the same availability set if they were not created in the same cloud service when they were created?

It looks like I would need to rebuild these VM's? If so that kinda sucks.

Please let me know if anyone knows a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a VM is created, it can't join an availability set.

However, the image for the VM is available in storage.  So, new VMs can be spun up, using the image, this time adding them to the set.  And rebuilding the VM from scratch is not needed.

Edit:

I've used the method above to bring up a VM, but I had forgotten that if your VM is running already, capture is the way to go.  I'd suggest these steps:

[Capture the image](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/) of your current VM.  This will run `sysprep` on it, so you will want to be careful with it.  (spin up a test VM and play with the steps until you feel confident to move to a production box)

Then when you create a new VM, specify your captured image and your availability set. Then the machine will come up with all your services running in the new set.

Comment: So you are saying that the image from the VM server that has been in use for a while is in storage and that it can be used to bring up a new VM of that same server if needed?

Comment: @Rob You bet.  Its usually a bit of a trick to find which one is which because they have long autogenerated names.  But once you find it, you should even be able to test it by making a copy of the blob and using that image to spin up the new VM.

Comment: @Rob There is some nuance to that.  Let me find some information for you.

Comment: @Rob check my edits.  Let me know if you have problems, and send me an upvote if it helps. :)

Comment: If its just a matter of moving the VM to an availability set, you can remove/delete it but keep the VHDs and then re-provision from those VHD's. Imaging is great when you want to create a "template" vm that you can then use to create the same starting point over and over. Giving the scenario you outlined, I don't know that you really need to go through the process of creating/managing images. Simply removing and re-provisioning should work fine. :)

Comment: What you said seems like it might also work but it seems that if I do that I am only collecting the data that was on that one attached disk and not the settings of the applications that were running on that server. I don't want to have to reconfigure everything again when I bring up the new VM. I just want to name it and add it to the domain. Wont I loose all the settings of the applications (that I believe are in the registry?) if I do it your way?

Comment: @rob No, registry will be maintained. The sysprep only removes the license info. All the app settings remain

Comment: That said, remember to test it before you start banging on production.

Comment: ok that seems legit. I will test it out. Thanks for the help.